# MPAndroidChart - How to add Annotations or images to the chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am currently working with the latest MPAndroidChart Library and am looking for a way to add annotations or images that would be clickable.

Example: once data reaches a certain value an event occurs that I want to be able to display to the user - there a multiple events that can occur so the annotations (not sure if that is the right word) or image could be added at any point in the chart.

Any pointers welcome.

Comment: i guess the best approach for you is to override [onEntityAdd](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnDrawListener.java) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work I downloaded the source code after implemented the features myself by allow a bitmap image be displayed along side the limit line.

Thanks to Philipp Jahoda for the help and for the library.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation of the YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-%28YLabels%29).

Focus on the `setSpaceTop(...)` and `setAxisMaxValue(...)` methods.

For the background: that is the **bar-shadow**, disable it by calling:

`barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false)`

Or change the color:

`barDataSet.setBarShadowColor(int color)`

Comment: Hi should i be using the custom marker views in order to achieve this or can it only be text labels that are added to the axis.  Also is there a way to add an image to the limit line tag and move that and hide the line, maybe as a work around. Again any info would be hugely welcomed.